# User entered Javascript security implications

Tags: javascript, security, customization, xss

I'm creating a web site that lets people create their own site using a subdomain. **Are there any security implications by letting people add custom javascript to their pages?** If so, which ones? XSS? Cookie sniffing? Could I make it work by sanitising the html?

Right now I'm disallowing it, but it'd be great to let people decide for themselves. I've noticed Github hosted pages have user entered javascript on them.

Comment: probably you should try it on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: haha, that's bureaucratic...

Comment: haha, give me -3 please

Comment: how in the h*** are users supposed to know where to post stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any security implications?

There are *loads*.  Anything you can do with javascript, a malicious site owner would be able to do on your sites.

- Grab a user's password from the login form and send it somewhere else before allowing them to login normally.
- Completely overwrite the page with something unrelated to how your application works.  (I've seen this done.  It was pharmacy spam.  It could be a phishing page.)
- Create an [open redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect).
- Cause visitors to the site to participate in a DDoS by repeatedly requesting the target page in the background.

You might notice that all of these are targeting the *users* of your sites.  It's unlikely that allowing javascript would lead to a compromise of your webserver unless it is by phishing or session-hijacking you when you visit the malicious website.

Scanning new javascript for dangerous keywords is unlikely to work as a malicious users can write different javascript using javascript itself.

Setting all cookies to `httponly` will protect them from javascript.  (You should be doing this anyway.)

You may decide that all of this is acceptable based on the relationship you have with your customers but you should be aware of exactly what you are allowing when you allow javascript.

Comment: So letting site administrators insert javascript should be ok since they probably won't be hacking their own site? The user problem only happens if the site administrator lets users insert js, right? Remember, this is a site to create your own site, like github pages or shopify.